# Can't connect to internet using Dlink DWA-130 (rev C1) usb stick on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless

chili555, if you're still reading this Q&A site, would you help me with this same problem as I saw your solution worked for the other user.  I followed your proposed steps as following (I replaced his device id to my device id "2001 3301" ) but it doesn't work for me.  Below is what I did and I still can't connect to the internet.  My wireless internet is still "DISABLED" when I run `sudo lshw -C network`, but the wired eth0 is not.  Thanks in advance.

1. Remove the device
2. In a terminal, do:

   `gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/network_drivers.conf`

   Add one long single line:

   `install rt2800usb /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install rt2800usb $CMDLINE_OPTS; /bin/echo "2001 3c25" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/rt2800usb/new_id`

Proofread twice, save and close the text editor.

3. Insert the device.
4. If it doesn't start immediately, you might have to do:

   `sudo modprobe rt2800usb`
5. Be certain that ndiswrapper is removed:

   `sudo apt-get purge ndiswrapper-common ndiswrapper-utils*`
6. reboot.

Answer (score 2):

The correct driver for your device is r8192u_usb. The file you added will be ineffective so please remove it:

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/network_drivers.conf
```

The driver requires firmware; let's confirm that it is present:

```
sudo modprobe r8192u_usb
dmesg | grep 8192
```

Are there any interesting messages? If it is missing firmware, get a temporary working internet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
wget ftp://ftp2.dlink.com/PRODUCTS/DWA-130/REVC/DWA-130_REVC_DRIVERS_0.06_LINUX.ZIP
unzip DWA-130_REVC_DRIVERS_0.06_LINUX.ZIP
sudo mkdir /lib/firmware/RTL8192U
sudo cp rtl8192u_linux_2.6.0006.1031.2008/firmware/RTL8192U/*  /lib/firmware/RTL8192U
```

Remove and reinsert the device and it should be working.

Also, sometimes DISABLED arises when the wireless switch or key combination is set to disable wireless; check

```
rfkill list all
```

Once I have further information, I will edit my answer to refine my proposed solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot and I really appreciate your answer.  I installed r8192u_usb driver and followed your steps and it works great now! Thanks, appreciate it!